# how to set text in counter page?

Tags: counters, text

How could I set a text like "Cover" inside the counter page like this image?

[image]

My actual behaviour shows blank (I'm skipping cover page until find the answer)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a compilable code of what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @Bernard, the renewcommand that werner sugest help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being displayed in the text box is just `\thepage`, so if you change `\thepage` to `Cover`, you'll get the desired result. However, you have to ensure that you change it back to its default definition (`\arabic{page}` or whatever) if you want it to work the same moving forward.

Below I patched the `\titlepage` command (defined by [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) as part of the `titlepage` environment) that is used when you issue `\maketitle`. Here's its original definition (when using a default setup):

```
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \cleardoublepage
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
        \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
```

The `\patchcmd` (from [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) usage below insert `\renewcommand{\thepage}{Cover}` just before `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Since the `titlepage` environment limits the scope of any changes, `\thepage` reverts back to its original definition once the environment closes (so there's no need to set it back to its original definition).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{A title}
\author{An Author}

\patchcmd{\titlepage}% <cmd>
  {\thispagestyle}% <search>
  {\renewcommand{\thepage}{Cover}\thispagestyle}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Depending on your setup, you may have to do some more extensive manipulation to achieve this result.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner, I only had to add the \patchcmd line and works with all my other code